# Python - Delete xlsx files from a folder

Tags: python, delete-file

I am trying to delete all `xlsx` files from a folder, note it has files of other extension. Given below is what I have tried:

```
path = '/users/user/folder'.  <-- Folder that has all the files
list_ = []
for file_ in path:
    fileList = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
    fileList1 = " ".join(str(x) for x in fileList)
        try:
            os.remove(fileList1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

But the above does not delete the xlsx files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
import os
import glob

path = '/users/user/folder'
for f in glob.iglob(path+'/**/*.xlsx', recursive=True):
    os.remove(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code to delete the xlsx or xls file
     import os

```
 path = r'your path '
 os.chdir(path)
 for file in os.listdir(path):
     if file.endswith('.xlsx') or file.endswith('.xls'):
         print(file)
         os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code as well to remove multiple .xlsx files in a folder.

```
import glob, os
path =r"folder path"
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
for i in filenames:
    os.remove(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use `os.listdir()` and `fnmatch`.
Try the below code .

```
`import os, fnmatch

 listOfFiles = os.listdir('/users/user/folder') #filepath 
 pattern = "*.xslx"  
 for entry in listOfFiles:  
     if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
        print ("deleting"+entry)
        os.remove(entry)`
```